# Is it possible to manually patch Stagefright?

Tags: root-access, updates, ota-update

Is it possible to manually patch the Stagefright vulnerability?

It looks like the latest OTA update that patches Stagefright also blocks many common avenues for rooting. Obviously, root + vulnerabilty = really bad. Is there some utility or console method of replacing, updating or disabling the affected media modules? If not: Why must I be so dependent on the manufacturer?

Comment: Can you install a custom ROM? Better, can you _compile_ one? If not then pretty much nope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but It's a lot easier to install CM for monthly security updates;

https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Main_Page